# Find object and remove specific array value inside it with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have this array of object, and I want to remove specific value from "subscriber" array

```json
    [
        {
          "slug": "just",
          "subscriber": ["0610988037", "1107405573"]
        },
        {
          "slug": "test",
          "subscriber": ["1107405573"]
        }
    ]
```

expected output

```json
    [
        {
          "slug": "just",
          "subscriber": ["0610988037"]
        },
        {
          "slug": "test",
          "subscriber": ["1107405573"]
        }
    ]
```

what I've tried this so far

```js
const index = _.findIndex(subs, { slug: "just" });
const newSubscriber = subs[index].subscriber.filter(
  (i) => i !== "1107405573"
);
subs[index].subscriber = newSubscriber;
```

the above code is work fine as expected but I don't think it's a good way

Comment: _"...but I don't think it's a good way"_ - Why? And why has this to be done with lodash (there are also `Array.prototype.findIndex()` and `Array.prototype.filter()`)? Can there be more than one object with `slug: "just"`? Can there be more elements in `subscriber` ths should be removed? Is it always the last element in the array or can the number be found in any place? ...

Comment: because I think with lodash code become easier in the eye, slug always unique, and the subscriber value will grow bigger and must be able to be deleted wherever it is.

Answer (score 1):

As the question leaves a few points open, the following is written under the assumptions that:

- there can be several objects with `arr[i].slug==="test"`
- and several with `arr[i].slug!=="test"`
- all values found in `arr[i].subscribers` of a "`test`-object" will be removed from all `arr[j].subscribers` arrays of "non-`test`-objects",
- "test"-objects will remain unchanged.

```js
const arr = [      {
    "slug": "test",
    "subscriber": ["555666","333","999"]
  },
  {
    "slug": "just",
    "subscriber": ["0610988037", "1107405573", "333"]
  },
  {
    "slug": "something else",
    "subscriber": ["0610988037", "123", "987"]
  },
  {
    "slug": "test",
    "subscriber": ["1107405573","123"]
  }
];

const filt=arr.reduce((a,c)=>(c.slug==="test" && c.subscriber.forEach(s=>a[s]=1),a),{}),
      res =arr.map(el=>({...el, subscriber:el.slug!=="test" ? el.subscriber.filter(s=>!filt[s]) : el.subscriber}))
      
console.log(res)
```

**Update:**

Taking into account the latest information from OP's comment:

- all `arr[i].slug` values are unique
- so, there can at most be one object with `arr[i].slug=="test"`
- all values found in `arr[i].subscribers` of the "`test`-object" will be removed from all `arr[j].subscribers` arrays of "non-`test`-objects",
- the same `subscriber` values can appear in several objects
- the "test"-object, if it exists, will remain unchanged.

The test input will now look slightly different but will still work with the same script:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "slug": "just",
    "subscriber": ["0610988037", "1107405573", "333"]
  },
  {
    "slug": "something else",
    "subscriber": ["0610988037", "123", "987"]
  },
  {
    "slug": "test",
    "subscriber": [ "555666","333","999", "1107405573","123"]
  }
];

const filt=arr.reduce((a,c)=>(c.slug==="test" && c.subscriber.forEach(s=>a[s]=1),a),{}),
      res =arr.map(el=>({...el, subscriber:el.slug!=="test" ? el.subscriber.filter(s=>!filt[s]) : el.subscriber}))
      
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I'm sorry forgot to mention that object with a slug is always unique, but subscriber value can be same across object